# URL Rewriting In PHP MVC Framework

Tags: php, apache, model-view-controller, url

I have made my own custom php framework which implements MVC design pattern.
In it, all URLs are constructed like this

```
mysite.com/index.php?route=controller/function/parameters/go/here
mysite.com/index.php?route=products/shirts/99
```

etc

I have put in place htaccess to remove index.php?route= part from URLs to make them
more SEF making them appear like this:

```
mysite.com/controller/function/parameters/go/here
mysite.com/products/shirts/99
```

I just want to append a suffix at the end of each URL like so:

```
mysite.com/controller/function/parameters/go/here.html
mysite.com/products/shirts/99.html
```

Probably htaccess can be put to use for acheiving that or possibly
some other solutions.

Any ideas please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to add a `.html` suffix to pages that aren't pure HTML. It's no benefit for SEO or users - actually it probably makes it worse since it's unnecessary fluff.

Comment: You are right, but some users have asked me to add this functionality into the framework, that is why i am looking for a solution around this.

Comment: If you're asking how to append the .html to the links your framework is generating (instead of a mod_rewrite rule that parses the links), then there's no real way to answer it without knowing the framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're taking the 'nice' urls then rewriting them to your index.php with the request rewritten to a get var or 'route'.

There are some problems you'll run into in the future, one will be how to deal with get vars in the request (if I recall dealing with a similar concept years ago).

Personally, I would just setup your .htaccess to send all requests that are not valid files/directories to your bootstrap/index.php file. Then do the parsing in PHP, not in a overly complex mod_rewrite. **You're already parsing the 'route' get var, why not just parse the whole request?**

At that point the first step of you index.php file would be to:

- Remove the . extension (or identify the request as html/xml/json/etc)
- Remove any kind of base URL.
- Parse the remainder like you do the route get var.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you say you have used htaccess to remove route= and you want to also remove a .html suffix. I think you are approaching it the wrong way.

I would have all the links in your app pointing to your preferred URLs and then have htaccess PUT IN in the route= and the index.php elements

So a link looks like this:

```
<a href="mysite.com/controller/function/parameters/go/here.html" />
```

and you can use an htaccess rule similar to Nicky's ton convert that into:

```
mysite.com/index.php?route=controller/function/parameters/go/here.html
```

In fact Nicky's will work fine. You have the option of removing the .html suffix in your index.php code or from the htaccess rule - easier from PHP in my opinion.

If you want to remove .html using htaccess then this will probably work (untested):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ index.php?route=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer Steve, but you probably did not understand my question correclty.

I don't want to remove html access, i want to add it to each URI but i wonder how to do it?

I am using a framework which automatically generates URIs based on route. So i can not put in links with html suffix added to them.

I hope i clarified this time aroud.

Still looking for a solution !!

Comment: simply, how to add html suffix to each url?

Comment: Are you asking to have all <a> tags appended with a .HTML suffix? htaccess won't do that, you need to create your URLs from your PHP framework and then convert them BACK into a call to index.php in htaccess. Sounds like you need to update your framework.

Answer (score 1):

Like others, I think the appending needs to happen in your framework.

I imagine that you have a function like:
$html->link('products/shirts/99');

That function should add the '.html'.

Your url handler should look like:

//$query  products/shirts/99.html

$l = explode ($query, '/');
$last = length($l);
$l[$last-1] = substring($l[$last-1] , find($l[$last-1] ,'.html')) //I am doing the args from memory so please check them.

This is how CakePHP's index.php would be modified.  I suggest you  look at that code as a guide.

Comment: yo right David, finally i have come up with that solution :) Thanks to all who replied...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer Nicky, but i dont see html suffix in the code above. anyways i havent tried that yet.